# Regular expression in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, anemone

http://www.example.com/books?_pop=mheader

What would be the regular expression to match this and any URL that has "books" in the URLs as one of the pattern matches ? This site has a books category and various other sub-categories under that. How do I traverse down to search all the URLs for book ?

```
require 'anemone'
Pattern = %r[(\/books)*]
Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_pages_like(Pattern) do |page|
    puts page.url
  end
end
```

Comment: If you're using `%r[...]` then you won't need to backslashify your slashes. Also note that constants like your pattern should be `ALL_CAPS` and classes should be `MixedCase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://rubular.com/ is a useful tool to test regex for Ruby.

The regex would be simple, `/http:\/\/.+(books)/`. It matchs `http://` as well to help ensure it is a url. Here is a [rubular test](http://rubular.com/r/yMoLlBgc84) against http://www.example.com/reference-books-2300.

Comment: I updated the rubular example to make the regex match that link

Answer (score 1):

The pattern to match /books in your url should just be "/books"

This is a good site to test your regular expressions http://regexpal.com to ensure you have at least that part of your code right.